# reactjs doesn't run functions inside Object.assign

Tags: json, reactjs, object

Add on to the question here: [Merge two JSON data into one with particular key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403409/merge-two-json-data-into-one-with-particular-key-values)

balldata.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "color": "red",

  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "color": "blue",
  }]
```

court.json:

```
[
  {
    "court_id": 2001,
    "ball_in_use": "1",
  },
  {
    "court_id": 2005,
    "ball_in_use": "2",
  }]
```

Now, I want to map two different json data base on it's ID.

so instead of:

```
const result = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, {[c.court_id] : q[i].color})))
```

I tried:

```
const result = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, {[c.court_id] : function(){
   console.log("this log did not run at all")
   for(var j=0; j<balldata.length; j++){
      if(i.court_id == balldata.id){
         return balldata[j].color;
      }
   }
}
})))
```

my output:

```
return (
    <ul>
      {result.map(r => (
        <li>
          Court id - {r.court_id} | Ball colour - {r.color}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

I did an console.log to see why I didn't get the result I wanted, but it turns out, my function did not run at all. Why is that so? I did the function based on the answer in:  [Why doesn't an if/else statement work in Object.assign() and .map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689303/why-doesnt-an-if-else-statement-work-in-object-assign-and-map)

Comment: Can you also post the input json data? And the prefered outpu too

Comment: edited the JSON. right now the code above only map the color by the position of courtdata (if court data is at position [2], then color is [2]), but now I want to map if by `ball in use`. e.g. if court data has an `ball in use` of 10, the color will be mapped by ball id 10.

Comment: You should also post a sample output. How the output should look

Comment: @TheAlpha93 I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

As per the problem statement, there will be some use cases

- `courtdata` has `ball_in_use`(e.g '3') which is not linked with any from `balldata`.
- `balldata` and `courtdata` array are shuffled.
- `balldata` and `courtdata` array are in same order.

For use case 1, in the below example, I'm showing `"No color assigned"` string to that extra entity. You can remove that as well...

So final code would be :

```js
 const final = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) =>
        p.map((c, i) => {
          const colored = q.find(val => val.id === c.ball_in_use);
          return {
            ...c,
            color: colored ? colored.color : "no colour assigned"
          };
        })
      );
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-dmk5h